# Objective C: Is there a way to call class methods on a class object without compiler complaints?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, class, methods

If you have a class object is there a way to use it to call class methods of that class. For example, if you have class A with method `+ (void)foo` defined how can you achieve something like the example below without the compiler warning that it can't find the method foo:

```
A* object = [[A alloc] init];
id objectClass = [object class];
[objectClass foo]; // complains that the method is not found
```

Comment: Please post the actual interface file (.h), the code where you're making this call, and the actual compiler output.  This should work.

Comment: Make sure both in *interface* and *implementation* you have `+` before method `foo`.

Comment: Sorry I posted in haste. Please see the edits above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a class method in your .h:

MyClass.h

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {    
}
+(void) test;

@end
```

MyClass.m

```
@implementation MyClass

-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];

    return self;
}

+(void) test
{
    NSLog(@"Test executed");
}

@end
```

You can then just call it like this:

```
MyClass* myClass = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];

[[myClass class] test];
```

Edit:

If the problem is the compiler warning, just create a @protocol that defines the foo method you want to call. 
Instead of calling:

```
id objectClass = [object class];
```

Try this;

```
id<MyProtocol> myCastedObject = (id<MyProtocol>)object;
[myCastedObject class] foo];
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create instances to call *Class methods*. Create instance if you have to call *instance methods*.

Method `+ (void)foo` of class `A` should be called as,

```
[A foo];
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran a quick test using one of my classes and was able to make it work using your syntax.
What errors are you getting?
What you are basically doing by the way is

```
  [A foo];
```

Calling a static member of the class.  This will only work with methods marked as static with the + sign.

Comment: sorry I posted too soon. My ultimate question is how do you get the compiler not to complain. Please see my edits above

Comment: Ah, when I did my test I used the class name instead of objectClass, why are you not doing it that way? Or simply doing the one liner above?

Comment: The example I gave was contrived and not what I'm really trying to do. In my actual code I have an array of of different class objects that I have to call a class method on and so can't use the class name.

Comment: only thing I can think of is creating a class that has your common methods (assuming you have common methods) and inherit that with your current classes, then you can access your objects as that class?

Comment: They are class methods, not static methods.